# JQuery UI date picker works only after re-focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The following code opens date picker only after I click in .datepicker field, click somewhere else, and then click in .datepicker again.

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".datepicker", function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
});
});
```

Please advise how to make it work without the "preparatory click".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` to target the currently selected input, and use the `show` method to open the datepicker programatically.

It's also a good idea to only do this once per input, which you can do by checking whether a datepicker already exists on it.

Something like:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".datepicker", function() {
  if ( !$(this).data("ui-datepicker") ) {
    $(this).datepicker();
    $(this).datepicker("show");
  }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ca3vj3od/

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    });
});
```

Comment: add this script with your dynamic content